# showing row axis names in datazen

Tags: ssas, mdx, datazen-server

I'm working on datazen and ssas 
when I tried to display a measures for a certain dimension for example "number of blocks in visited locations vs unvisited" .. SQL Analysis Service  showed me the result as a matrix

```
+-------------------------------------+
|            |number of visited blocks|
|-------------------------------------- 
|visited     | 10                     | 
|-------------------------------------| 
|not visited | 20                     |
+-------------------------------------+
```

using a code

```
SELECT 

          [Measures].[actual number for blocks]  on columns

          [DimStatus].[VisitStatus].[VisitStatus] on rows
        FROM [Model]
```

when I wrote the same code in data zen it gave me

```
    +-------------------------------------+
    |            |number of visited blocks|
    |-------------------------------------- 
    |1           | 10                     | 
    |-------------------------------------| 
    |2           | 20                     |
    +-------------------------------------+
```

which hide an important axis name... I wanted it to plot charts on developer tool... anyone knows how to show `visted` , `not visited` instead of `1`,`2`

Comment: Looks like the key value is the default - can you change this within BIDS so that the name of the member is the default?

Comment: As said above, you need to set the name property for the attribute. Right now it seems only key is set.